# Is it possible to write a few StringArray values into one String?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to write a part of an `String` array into a `String` but I just stuck at a problem.
The disposal of the value of line is always like this: "`status.test.status.close.name      = Closed`".
The only static of this value is "`status`." and "`.name`". I just want to get the part between "`status`." and "`.name`". With the code below I get this result: "`status.test.status.close`". My question now is, is it possible to delete parts of an `array`, for example: `technicalNames.delete["status."];`? Or does anyone has another hint how to realize it?

```
public void setTechnicalName(File javaFile) throws IOException {
    if(javaFile.exists()) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(javaFile));
        String line = null;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        if (line.contains("In approval") || line.contains("In Approval") || line.contains("In review") || line.contains("In Review") || line.contains("Closed")){
                System.out.println(line);
                String[] technicalNames = line.split(".name");
                String technicalName = technicalNames[0];
                System.out.println(technicalName);

        }

        reader.close();
    }
}
```

That is the .xml file i read out:

```
status.test.status.close.name      = Closed
status.test.status.in.approval.name = In approval
status.test.status.in.review.name     = In review

test.field.approver1      = Approver
test.field.lookupworkflow = 
test.field.temp           = temp
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't delete parts of a string - you can only copy parts of a string into a new string. Please provide us with a input->output mapping of actual vs. desired value and your code so far to achieve this mapping.

Comment: You should probably use StringBuilder. It gives you more control of the strings & is easier to use

Comment: you can replace part of the string with an empty string result of which is equivalent to delete :)

Comment: @IlyaOvesnov not if you want to join again afterwards. You'd end up with double `..`

Comment: @IlyaOvesnov technically speaking, Java Strings are immutable, so there's no "replacing" but "copying into a new String with parts omitted".

Comment: @Zack Newsham and Smutje that is why I said: "result of which is equivalent"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are interested in parts between `status` and `.name`. You can try this way of doing it.

```
public  static void setTechnicalName(File javaFile) throws IOException {
    if(javaFile.exists()) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(javaFile));
        String line = null;
        int statusOffet = "status.".length();
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            int indexOfStatus = line.indexOf("status");
            int indexOfName = line.lastIndexOf(".name");                
            boolean isReqLine = line.contains("In approval")
                                        || line.contains("In Approval")
                                        || line.contains("In review")
                                        || line.contains("In Review") 
                                        || line.contains("Closed");

            if(isReqLine && indexOfStatus != -1 && indexOfName != -1){
                System.out.println(line);
                String stage = line.substring(indexOfStatus + statusOffet, indexOfName); 
                System.out.println(stage);
            }

        }
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT** : as per comment to match format, I have included `"."` when calculating offset and used `indexOf`

Comment: Hey, that also includes a logic failure, because of the second status. The result I want to get is "test.status.close" but after running your code it returns only ".close" because the indexOfStatus is starting at the second status in the line. Is there a opportunity to let it start from the first status?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have status defined twice. So assuming you are referring to the first status, and the desired result is to print out `test.status.close` you could do this if you knew that indexes 0 and n-1 would be not of interest:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String[] parts = line.split(".name")[0].split("\\.");
for(int i = 1; i < parts.length - 1; i++){
    builder.append(parts[i]);
    if(i < parts.length - 1){
    builder.append(".");
}
System.out.println(builder.toString())
```

Comment: I tried yours but I think there are some mistakes in your code? Shouldn't be parts an array? No matter if it is right or wrong, it doesn't seem to work, because parts is always empty.

Comment: Now it is working, but there are still some logic failures inside.
Firstly it should be `i < parts.length` not `i < parts.length -1`, because otherwise i get "test.status." as the result. But even with `i < parts.length` the result is "test.status.close." so one dot to much at the end. And for lines with 4 words between "status." and ".name" it doesn't work at all. Any idea?

Comment: the additional `.` is the if statement. Define "doesnt work at all"?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to split your given line into parts, you can do it similar to

```
final String string = "status.test.status.close.name = Closed";
final String[] split = string.substring(0, string.indexOf("=")).split("\\.");
System.out.println("split = [" + split[0] + ", " + split[1] + ", " + split[2] + ", " + split[3] + ", " + split[4] + "]"); // split = [status, test, status, close, name ]
```

and pick the appropriate values out of `split` afterwards.

Comment: I would have done this before, but the problem is, that sometimes there are four words between status and name. That's why I need an dynamic solution for the problem.

That is the .xml I read out:

`status.test.status.close.name      = Closed 

status.test.status.in.approval.name = In approval 

status.test.status.in.review.name     = In review`

Comment: Then why don't you pick everything but the first and last item?

Comment: Because I never know how many items will be there. Is there a function to do something like split[lastItem]?

Comment: But what about `split.length - 2` as last item?

Comment: As long as I don't know how many items are coming before split.length -2, I cannot use it. Otherwise there would be one item to much or to less.

Comment: I don't understand, you can use the dynamic length of the result array and skip the first and last entry, what is the problem?